# Managing several code bases that share overlapping function and classes

Tags: php, version-control

We have a website that has about 9 distinct code bases for various functions of it, that would run on different servers.

We use use SVN and scripts that copy the code from the repo to the staging servers for testing, so that's all automated. My issue is, there are functions and classes that exist in different codes bases, and they need to be kept in sync. So fixing a little bug in a function that gets a time offset, would require to me to go manually edit 5 other files in 5 other code bases. Once the code footprint grows, I wont even remember that this particular function may also exist in 5 other places.

What would be the best way to handle this type of stuff without just creating 2-3 massive "functions.php" files and cloning them to all code bases every single time?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a new SVN repository(which contains the shared classes, files etc) and linking it as an external repository into your other project repositories that require shared code.

So for example you have numerous projects:

1. Project A
2. project B

etc and so forth.

Lets say both these projects share numerous classes.

I think one way to go forward would be to create a new SVN repository which includes the shared classes and then link this SVN repository into your existing repositories.

**Advantages**

Will allow you to have uniform & shared code deployed to all projects, without having to manually edit x amount of files each time your code repository is updated.

Additionally I would look into deploying your code using [phing(A deployment tool)](http://www.buildmeister.com/articles/automating_the_php_deployment_process_with_phing,_dbdeploy_and_ftp) if you are not doing so already. it really is very good & useful. The link provided is a nice simple tutorial.

Comment: The deployment is fairly bulletproof already, can deploy to 100+ servers with a single click if necessary. As for the repo you suggested, its not exactly ideal as the shared classes and functions are not just present everywhere. Some code bases might only need the emailing functions, while others will need functions that deal with Gearman workers, etc. Pulling ALL this stuff to ALL the servers would in theory work, but it creates a lot of unnecessary code that will never be used, but will be constantly updated.